# Is there a way to keep the browser window open after the test execution in RobotFramework?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am looking to keep the browser window open even after test execution.
I would like to keep it open indefinitely.
As of now , as a work around I am just using `sleep()` to keep the window from closing.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: @Prune I think the dup  target [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044315/how-to-keep-chrome-browser-window-open-after-selenium-script-finishes-on-python) was about _re-use the same window_ while this specific question is about _keep the window from closing_, both of them seems to be different. Can you have a re-look please?

Comment: Thanks; I clicked on the wrong duplicate.
This question *has* been handled many times.

Comment: Please a [mcve] that closes the browser after it's finished. I'm willing to bet you're telling it to close.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, the *WebDriver* service should stop once your script ends due to [this code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py#L174).

However if you want *Chrome* and *ChromeDriver* to stay open afterwards, you can add the *experimental option* **`detach`**  when initializing the chromedriver.

Through *Selenium-Python* client you can:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple - do not call `Close Browser` at the end.

Comment: If you call "Open Browser  <url>", then it closes at the end...

Comment: Yes, in 2023 it really does; the answer was applicable to the state of Selenium and SeleniumLibrary when it was given. @djg

Answer (score 0):

In a previous Stack Overflow question about connecting to the Chrome remote-debugging-port I provided [an example for connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53324533/6152737) to a running chrome instance using it's Dev Port.

This will functionally do what you want and as such may be an alternative to no closing as suggested by @Todor and @Bryan.